# Change Visuals On Another Tab

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar view in my Xcode app and it has two views. View 1 and View 2. When i press a button on View 1 i want a label on View 2 to say hi but i am having trouble doing this. Does anyone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the button method, you can get a reference to the tab bar controller with the view controller's tabBarController property. From that reference, you can get the view2 controller reference from the tab bar controller's viewControllers array. Once you have that reference, you need to change that view controller's tabBarItem.title property, and then finally, you need to update the tab bar controller's viewControllers array.

```
    -(IBAction)ChangeTabTitle:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *cont2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    cont2.tabBarItem.title =@"Hi";
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
}
```

Comment: Hi why would i change the image property, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hi i ended up using NSNotificationCenter, thanks for the help

Comment: @Cristian, That way certainly works too. I've updated my answer to show the code I used -- the code looks simpler than the explanation.